# Importing .sty package on linux

Tags: packages, linux

Hi I'd like to use the `jeff.sty` file located at `https://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/pubs/tex/jeffe.sty` as an added package.

Although I've downloaded the file, I haven't been able to figure out where/how I should link this file so I can use the macros with a `\usepackage{jeff.sty}` command.

Comment: the simplest is just to save it in the same place as your document

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle that works. Just curious if there a directory where for Texmaker (or other editors) where you can keep the downloaded `.sty` files so they can be called directly without having to be put in a project folder every time.

Comment: Think twice before store  files in ~/textmf instead that in the working directory. Yes, it is handy for  packages used in several projects, but also easier  forget that the project need a  .sty file of  ~\texmf when making  the backups.

Answer (score 1):

TeX Live looks for packages in the so-called texmf tree. This is a folder structure specified in the [TeX Directory Structure](https://tug.org/tds/tds.html). Long story short, on Arch-based distros the texmf tree is by default the `~/texmf` folder (so a directory `texmf` in your home folder). The source of user-installed packages should go in the subfolder `/tex/latex/<packagename>/` (assuming you use LaTeX).

So in your example, you would copy `jeff.sty` to `~/texmf/tex/latex/jeff/jeff.sty`.

EDIT:
For more distro-specific info, see the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live#texmf_trees_and_Kpathsea).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux this is usually in `~/texmf`. Anyway you can find out by running the terminal command `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`

The directory has a structure to keep things tidy. Your LaTeX packages should be placed in the subdirectory `tex/latex/`.